# Разная отрисовка table с tr, у которого height =100%, в Хроме и ФФ

Tags: html, css

В Хроме и ФФ по-разному рисует сектор `AAAAAA-BBBBBB` (синий) и `CCCCCCCCCCCCCC`.
Хром рисует правильно, ФФ растягивает `AAAAAA-BBBBBB` и сжимает `CCCCCCCCCCCCCC`

Плюс глюк в хроме - как-то странно реагирует на растяжение окна вниз. Не пересчитывает при сжатии обратно размер таблицы и включает вертикальный скролл.

Полный пример на [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dtouL6xL/2/).

```
<body>
<table width="100%" height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
<col width="450px">
<col>
<col width="350px">
<tr valign="top">
    <td rowspan="2">
        <table width="100%" height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: red">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
                aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
                aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="100%" valign="top">
                <td style="background-color: green">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
                aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
                aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td style="background-color: blue"> AAAAAAAAA </td>
    <td style="background-color: blue"> BBBBBBBBB </td>
</tr>
<tr valign="top" height="100%">
    <td colspan="2"> CCCCCCCCCCCCCC </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Как пофиксить?

[image: картинки]

Comment: Было бы неплохо добавить скриншоты в разных браузерах. Почему не используете HTML5?